# Optional Interface issue

Tags: java, option-type

```
RezerwacjaInfoDTO getRezerwacjaInfo(int rezerwacjaId) throws Exception {

    Integer osobaId = Math.abs(loginMgr.getLoggedUserInfo().getUserId());
    RezerwacjaInfoDTO rezInfo = rezMgr.getRezerwacjaInfo(rezerwacjaId);

    return Optional
            .ofNullable(rezInfo)
            .filter(rez -> rez.getOsobaId() == osobaId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Brak rezerwacji o podanym numerze"));
}
```

When I call it:

```
getRezerwacjaInfo(81504)
```

I got Exception, but rezInfo.getOsobaId() == 81504 (i see it in debugger)

when I remove this line:

```
.filter(rez -> rez.getOsobaId() == osobaId)
```

function returns object RezerwacjaInfoDTO.

What is rong with this line??

Comment: and what is the value of `osobaId` & `rezInfo.getOsobaId() `?

Comment: you should use .equals on object types: `rez.getOsobaId().equals(osobaId)`

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I guess the exception OP is talking about is `.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Brak rezerwacji o podanym numerze"));`

Comment: @k5_  you're right. It was stupid mistake, thakns.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable rezInfo is null then your optional throws exception also rezInfo.getOsobaId() == osobaId is true then exception occurs.

When you remove the filter it does not throws exception because your rezInfo is not null.

May be another alternative is to handle optional in caller method.

```
Optional<RezerwacjaInfoDTO> getRezerwacjaInfo(int rezerwacjaId) {

    Integer osobaId = Math.abs(loginMgr.getLoggedUserInfo().getUserId());
    RezerwacjaInfoDTO rezInfo = rezMgr.getRezerwacjaInfo(rezerwacjaId);

    return Optional
            .ofNullable(rezInfo);
}

void callerMethod() throws Exception {
    getRezerwacjaInfo(...)
            .filter(rez -> rez.getOsobaId() == osobaId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Brak rezerwacji o podanym numerze"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explenation. It was stupid mistake, should be rez.getOsobaId().equals(osobaId)

Comment: @Olek just declare `osobaId` as `int` and `==` will work as intended (and it will even improve the performance).